# Kendo grid adding another data source as object to model on save

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, asp.net-core-webapi

So I’m working on learning Kendo in an effort to push our employer closer towards purchasing a few licenses for our new web development agenda.
I have an Core2 API set up and functioning on an internal web server and am attempting to use that to create an administration page for another application.

What would cause this (described below) to occur and what's the best way to handle it or what I'm attempting?

Setting up the grid and displays is done but having a problem getting data back to the API, correctly.
It seems to be an odd problem related to having drop down lists as the data source for 2 fields.

When the page first loads, the model matches that as defined in the data source schema.

```
schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    projectName: { validation: { required: true, max: 150 } },
                    projectDescr: { validation: { required: true, max: 500 } },
                    projectOwner: { validation: { required: true, max: 125 } },
                    projectCoder: {type:"number", required:true, validation: { required: true }, from:"projectCoder"},
                    projectCoderNavigation: {  from: "projectCoderNavigation", nullable:false},
                    projectEstHours: {type: "number", validation: {min: 0}},
                    statusId: { validation: { required: true },  from:"statusId"},
                    statusReason: { validation: { max: 125 },from:"statusReason" }
                }
            }
```

Kendo grid columns

```
columns: [
            {field: "projectName", title: "Project Name"},
            {field: "projectDescr", title: "Description", editor: descrEditor},
            {field: "projectOwner", title: "Project Owner"},
            {field: "projectCoder", title: "Programmer", editor:  programmerDDL, template:"#= projectCoderNavigation.adName#" },
            {field: "statusId", title:"Status", editor: statusDDL, template:"#= statusReason#"},
            {field: "projectEstHours", title: "Estimated Hours"}
```

Model data returned from server (chrome dev tools). Here it matches above model, with the exception that the projectCoderNavigation property also includes projectTime, Tasks, and a repeat of projects.

[image: Model data returned from server]

When I click the add new record button, the model data is updated with blank data correctly.

[image: model data is updated with blank data correctly]

However once I hit save, the model changes and a new object “adName” is added and matches the data source for the drop down list used for selection. 
The projectCoder remains 0, projectCoderNavigation remains null, and the other fields are updated.

[image: after save - before actual POST]

And of course, POST fails due to invalid model state.

[image: fiddler fail input not valid]

## EDIT

This is the function to populate the DDL editor.

```
function programmerDDL(container, options) {
   // var input = $("<input/>");
    //input.attr("projectCoderNavigation.adName",options.field);
   // input.append(container);

    $('<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox"  name="adName"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            //valuePrimitive: true,
            dataTextField: "adName",
            dataValueField: "id",
            dataSource: usersListDs,
            text: "Select someone"

            });
}
```

This is assigning the editor to the dropdown.

```
{field: "projectCoder", title: "Programmer", editor:  programmerDDL, 
template:"#= projectCoderNavigation.adName#" },
```

## Note:

I have managed to work it out so that I assign the projectCoder via the parameter map, but still have the empty projectCoderNavigation property and the unwanted "adName" object in the options.models.

```
parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
        console.log("model: "+options.models);
        if (operation === "create") {
            options.models[0].projectCoder = options.models[0].adName.id;
            }
            console.log(options.models);
            console.log(kendo.stringify(options.models));
     return  options.models;
         }
     }
```

### EDIT 2

So I've progressed to where I can verify the request is reaching the API and will probably close this question, but I'll provide more information first.

When save is clicked, the API receives the POST request. However, the data from the payload isn't used by the method.

[image: Mutliple signatures I've attempted]

The response is HTTP code 500, as the model was null and the insert failed due to foreign key constraints.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_att_projects_att_Users". The conflict occurred in database
>   "ASSIST_TimeTracking", table "dbo.att_users", column 'id'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

[image: request headers from chrome dev tools]

Comment: What does the code for the dropdown template look like? How are you sending the selected value of the dropdown to projectCoder?

Comment: @Supersnake I added a bit more details and I'm not exactly sure how to get the projectCoder selected id back to the model, but have a work around atm.

Comment: Edited to ad more information. API is receiving the request but not actually using the data contained or passing it to the method.